# How does domain resolution occur when resolv.conf is blank and your server has a static IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, resolv.conf

I've installed ubuntu server 10.04 on a computer in my LAN.  From my router control panel I set it up to be Static DHCP.

My resolv.conf file had the output

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

I removed that line and saved .conf file, but I am still able to ping websites from my server's terminal.  How can domain names be resolved to ip addresses even though this file is blank?

Comment: Have you cleared the DNS cache since removing resolv.conf or had it resolve anything that wouldn't have been in the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nscd is most likely caching the results. Another possibility is that you are running a dns server on your machine, since by default with an empty "nameserver" the resolver routines use "localhost" (man resolv.conf for details)

Comment: It's like you have a 6th sense.  I now remember including bind9 when I installed ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2):

It must have cached those IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

`nscd` is most likely the service caching your names, stopping or restarting it should clear up the cache for you.